# What is the preposition in the "She spoke in a low voice"?

Tags: prepositions

I think it is , IN. but my books says it is LOW .

could you please explain me if LOW is right.

Comment: Your book is wrong. You are correct. *Low* is an adjective.

Comment: [*In* is a preposition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in). [*Low* is an adjective](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/low) in this usage. This question is answered by a dictionary, which means it's general reference.

Answer (score 1):

The word *in* is  a preposition.  The entire preposition phrase *in a low voice* acts an an adverb in the sentence.  It could easily be replaced withe the single word *softly*.  The word *low* is an adjective.

Another good forum for questions like this is:

[English Language for Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Note that ELL also requires a modicum of research, even if the OP doesn't really know where to look. A dictionary is generally a good start.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I agree with you completely.  I will mention this in my future answers.